# Problems with getting started with node.js and puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am quite new to programming and today decided to attempt and create a node.js and puppeteer project with the purpose of scraping website into a .txt file. I ran into issues straight away since for the most part I have no idea what I'm doing. After installing node.js and puppeteer, I was guided by some videos and articles I found to create my first project. In the command prompt using `mkdir` and later `cd` I was able to create and access the new directory, but I started running into problems with `npm init`. It only places the file `package.json` in the repository, but there isn't a `package-lock` or `node_modules` file anywhere. No idea what they do but thought this was a problem. When I open cmd and try to run the app by typing `node app.js` it returns `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\emili\app.js'` along with some other gobble. What should I do, to be able to run the simple application I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are missing some key knowledge on how NodeJS works, but in order to fix your issue (for now), you will need to take a few steps.

First, in your working directory (where the `package.json` is), you'll need to install your modules.

1. Run `npm install puppeteer`. This will do two things, create the `node_modules` folder and create the `package-lock.json` file.
2. Create a file named `app.js` (either manually or by running the command `touch app.js`) in your working directory, and put the following content inside of it:

   ```js
   console.log('Hello, World!');
   ```
3. Save the changes to `app.js` and then run `node app.js` in your terminal. You should see `Hello, World!` output to the terminal.

The reason `npm install puppeteer` created the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file is because they weren't needed beforehand.

When you run `npm install PACKAGE_NAME`, you're installing a module (otherwise known as a `package`), thus it creates the `node_modules` folder so that it will have a place to put the module so that your code can access it. It also creates the `package-lock.json` file, which is used to track the module versions inside of your project.

With this information, I request you go back to the tutorial you were originally following and try going through it again and attempting to understand each of the core concepts before writing any real code.

Comment: Thank you so much, 24h later I feel so stupid about this. I anyone ever stumbles on to this thread, make sure to install puppeteer inside the project folder. I'm not familiar with how packages work, so I thought that just running npm install puppeteer before even creating the folder with package.json would do the trick